# Making outgoing calls from browser using Twilio - call is terminated automatically

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I'm trying to make outgoing calls from my twilio trial account. I'm referring this [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/outgoing-calls#hello-client-twiml-2php). Based on this link, I have created one page called *hello-client-twiml.php* with following code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// put a phone number you've verified with Twilio to use as a caller ID number
$callerId = "+xxxxxxxxxx";

// put your default Twilio Client name here, for when a phone number isn't given
$number   = "jenny";

// get the phone number from the page request parameters, if given
if (isset($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'])) {
    $number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber']);
}

// wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
// by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
if (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $number)) {
    $numberOrClient = "<Number>" . $number . "</Number>";
} else {
    $numberOrClient = "<Client>" . $number . "</Client>";
}
?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="<?php echo $callerId ?>">
          <?php echo $numberOrClient ?>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

and *hello-client-monkey.php* page with the code:

```
<?php
include "vendor/autoload.php";

use Twilio\Jwt\ClientToken;

// put your Twilio API credentials here
$accountSid = 'your_sid_here';
$authToken  = 'your_auth_token';

// put your TwiML Application Sid here
$appSid = 'APXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$capability = new ClientToken($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid);
$capability->allowClientIncoming('jenny');
$token = $capability->generateToken();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Client Monkey 4</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="//static0.twilio.com/resources/quickstart/client.css"
      type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

      Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $token; ?>");

      Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
        $("#log").text("Ready");
      });

      Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
        $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
      });

      Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
        $("#log").text("Successfully established call");
      });

      Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
        $("#log").text("Call ended");
      });

      Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
        $("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);
        // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
        conn.accept();
      });

      function call() {
        // get the phone number to connect the call to
        params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
        Twilio.Device.connect(params);
      }

      function hangup() {
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="call" onclick="call();">
      Call
    </button>

    <button class="hangup" onclick="hangup();">
      Hangup
    </button>

    <input type="text" id="number" name="number"
      placeholder="Enter a phone number to call"/>

    <div id="log">Loading pigeons...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Twilio console,  [TwiML apps page](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/dev-tools/twiml-apps/), I have added http://mywebsite.com/hello-client-monkey.php as **Voice->Request URL**.

Now, when I run the page *hello-client-monkey.php*, the call is getting terminated automatically and in [twilio console logs](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/calls) I'm getting error log as:

```
WARNING
   12200 Schema validation warning
DESCRIPTION
 Cannot find the declaration of element 'html'.
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Looks like you need to configure your TwiML application with the `hello-client-twiml.php` URL, not the `hello-client-monkey.php` URL.

Comment: @Devin...I have configured TwiML with the `hello-client-twiml.php` url. But it is not working and getting twilio console log like : `There were no HTTP Requests logged for this event.`

Comment: @DevinRader..Also my twilio number is US number and I'm trying to call to a mobile in India...Is that a restriction for trial accounts?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/12200

> Schema validation warning
>
> The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema.
> Please refer to the specific error and correct the problem.
>
> Possible Causes
>
> misspelled verbs, incorrect case for verbs, misspelled or unknown
> attributes, unknown or unexpected nested elements.
>
> Possible Solutions
>
> check the line and column reported by the warning to see what part of
> your XML response caused the complaint

As Devin suggests above, your TwiML application expects twiml as you've defined in *hello-client-twiml.php*.

Comment: @Megan...I have configured TwiML with the `hello-client-twiml.php` url. But it is not working and getting twilio console log like : `There were no HTTP Requests logged for this event.`